# django_markdown is not showing (python 2.7)

Tags: python, django

I want to add django_markdown in my blog. But it's not working.There is no error , still it is missing from blog.

*admin.py* code:

```
class EntryAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
      list_display =('title','created')
      prepopulated_fields ={'slug':('title',)}


admin.site.register(models.Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

*urls.py* code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/',include("django_markdown.urls")),
)
```

I'm using **django 1.7** and **python 2.7** .

Comment: Have you installed it and put in settings file under INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: You don't need the markdown url.  Follow the instructions here and show the relevant code in models https://github.com/klen/django_markdown

Comment: I removed Django_markdown part from blog. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: a while back I used markdown in a blog.  You can review my code here: https://github.com/jgoldstick/joelgoldstick.com.16